# JSF: How to implement an eclipse like console?

Tags: javascript, java, eclipse, jsf, jsf-2

I'm trying to set up a console on a jsf webapplication. Currently I'm using a textarea to display the output. I want it to work like the console in eclipse. It should autoscroll down if new lines are added, but it should also be possible to deactivate autoscrolling. And that's the problem. After adding new lines the textarea always jumps up and doesn't stay at its current position.

I also tried to save the current position with scrollTop, but this didn't work out.

What's your suggestion to go on?

Comment: My suggestion is to use a searchengine

Comment: Thanks for that helpful comment. I tried but I didn't find a solution for my problem. I didn't know that there is a primeface terminal. I will try to do it with the primeface terminal.

Comment: PrimeFaces terminal is more AND less then you need…

Comment: Okay, could you be more precise, please? I just want to show text and I don't need commands. The problem with textarea is the scrolling thing. How can I get that working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To accomplish my goal I used two textareas. One hidden textarea which is autoupdated by a backingbean and another a visible textarea to which I copy the value by using javascript. The visible textarea may **not** be autoupdated or rerendered.

xhtml:

```
<p:inputTextarea 
       id="txtHiddenConsole"
       value="#{consoleLogBean.log}"
       pt:data-autoUpdate="true">
</p:inputTextarea >
<p:inputTextarea id="txtConsole" >
```

Javascript

```
log = $('#txtHiddenConsole').val();
$('#txtConsole').val(log);
```

By using this workarround the scrollposition of the visible textarea won't be changed.

Answer (score 1):

Primefaces has a good Terminal component. See the demo on their showcase here: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/terminal.xhtml

Comment: Thanks Ernest! I've implemented the terminal. After executing a command I want each line to be shown one after another. Do have an idea how I can push new lines to the terminal until the command is terminated?

Comment: Looked at the documentation but didn't see any option to achieve that. However, I inspected the terminal fields and saw that they are just text input fields with class 'ui-terminal-input'. You could use some jQuery (already in primefaces) and register your own event handlers on fields with this class to decide before proceeding with the ajax call. I'm not very good with JS so I won't be more practical with this. Hope that helps.